# Не понимаю почему не работает код ( новичок как в юнити так и в сs)

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControler : MonoBehaviour
{
    {
    public float playerSpeed;
    public Rigidbody2D playerRB;
    private float movementX;

    private void Update()
        }
    {

        movementX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");


    }

    private void FizedUpdate()
    {


        Vector2 movement = new Vector2(movementX * playerSpeed, playerRB, velocity.y);
        playerRB.velocity = movement; 

    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помощи я новичок , и не особо понимаю в чом же всетаки причина .

Comment: `Не понимаю почему не работает код` Где код то?

Comment: не понял именно как оформить прошу прощение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас лишние `{` и `}` в коде, лучше покажу как должно быть, чем буду долго и упорно объяснять.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControler : MonoBehaviour
{
    // здесь была лишняя {
    public float playerSpeed;
    public Rigidbody2D playerRB;
    private float movementX;

    private void Update()
    // здесь была лишняя }
    {
        movementX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() // здесь была опечатка FizedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 movement = new Vector2(movementX * playerSpeed, playerRB.velocity.y); // здесь тоже была опечатка
        playerRB.velocity = movement; 
    }
}
```

Внимательнее копируйте код, если сами не пишете. Ну и учитесь писать самостоятельно.

Отвлекитесь от Unity, позанимайтесь чуть-чуть изучением C#: [Интерактивный учебник по основам C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/tutorials/hello-world).

Comment: я все исправил но некоторые ошибки я так и не понял почему есть прикреплю новый скрин

Comment: @CyberFortnite исправил, обратите внимание на все комментарии в коде

Comment: честно не понял почему так

Comment: @CyberFortnite слева от ответа галочка, нажмите, если все решилось.

Comment: в том то и дело что не решилось

Comment: @CyberFortnite обновите страницу, я же написал, что исправил код

Comment: спасибо вам большое

Comment: @CyberFortnite https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/tutorials/hello-world отвлекитесь от Unity, позанимайтесь чуть-чуть.

Comment: думаю вы правы лучше начать с азов ) спасибо еще раз .